# What is this disc-like switch called?

Tags: identification

The black disc on the left side of the Bluetooth speaker is used to seek music (previous track / next track). It rotates only halfway and centers automatically with some spring-mechanism. This is an image from an [amazon-review](https://www.amazon.in/gp/customer-reviews/R2L1AX0YYHORED) so this is the only image I have. I want to use the same for navigation but cannot find it anywhere.

[image: Photo of Bluetooth speaker from Amazon review]

Comment: It is probably a self-centering potentiometer or encoder.  Might not even be self-centering, if it has a protrusion inside which the manufacturer has placed between two springs.

Comment: @rdtsc Thanks. It's more like a push button on two sides which gets pressed when the wheel is rotated. I believe I can DIY this but I wanted the compact form-factor preferably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a two-way switch (i.e. slide to left or right from a central "off" position). Some include extra switch contacts for being pushed harder towards each left/right limit and being pushed inwards.

The ones I've used in the past were from Alps - now called Alps Alpine (similar parts may be available from other manufacturers).

An example of that type of switch is the [Alps Alpine SLLB range](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/e/products/category/muiti-control-device/sub/02/series/sllb/) e.g. the
[Alps Alpine SLLB120200](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/e/products/detail/SLLB120200/):

[image: Photo of Alps Alpine SLLB120200 switch]

(No association except as a customer.)